# Show that $x^{\frac{1}{2}} +x^{\frac{1}{3}}=1$ have atleast one real solution.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I tried to show that  $F(x) = x^{\frac{1}{2}} +x^{\frac{1}{3}}-1$ this function is monotonic but that doesn't seem to work. Also I am not allowed to use graphs. Is there some algebraic approach to solve this?

Comment: btw,  rather than telling us what you tried, show us what you tried would make the post better.

Comment: Thank you @Sil.

Answer (score 4):

Guide:

- Let $f(x) = x^\frac12 + x^\frac13$.
- Evaluate $f(0)$ and $f(1)$.
- Use intermediate value theorem (think of why can you use the theorem).

Comment: Is this the easiest way? I mean I will have to show first that this function is continuous

Comment: i do not know what do you mean by the easiest way.